# How to specifying generic return type in PyCharm + python2.7

Tags: python, pycharm, typing, docstring

How to define the docstring in following function?

```
def get_object(klass, **kwargs):
    """
    :rtype: ???
    """
    # perform some tasks
    return klass(**kwargs)
```

I've tried `klass`, `type(klass)`, `klass.__class__`,
they all didn't work in separated module files:

```
from sample.utils import get_object
from sample.models import User

u = get_object(User, name='test')
u.  # no PyCharm hint here
```

I also tried `:type klass: T` and `:rtype: T`, also not working :(

Can PyCharm support these kind of syntax in docstring?
How to document it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def get_obj(klass, **kwargs):
"""
:type klass: ((object) -> T) | T
:type kwargs: object
:rtype: T
"""
```

Class can be a lambda of its `__init__`, so you can use lambda's return type as the instance type of a class